# Failed: Filesystem preventing downloads. ( ftpext)

Tags: errors, ftp

I just move my server to Mac server before I use to be with GOdaddy was no problem updating framework of my theme

now I'm getting this error

`Failed: Filesystem preventing downloads. ( ftpext)`

not sure why but I've put this code in wp-config.php already

```
putenv('TMPDIR=' . ini_get('upload_tmp_dir'));

define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');

define('FTP_BASE', 'wpdirectory');

define('FTP_USER', 'myuser');

define('FTP_PASS', 'mypassword');

define('FTP_HOST', 'myftphost');

define('FTP_SSL', false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this line in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

Comment: This also fixed my "Failed to connect to FTP Server" error.  Thanks